# Dynamically Slice Tensor of Arbitrary Dims

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I'm writing a definition that needs to take slices of a tensor with an arbitrary number of dimensions. The slice will always be on the batch dimension of 0.

Here is a simple example of what I want:

```
def masktensor(X, array_of_indices):
    return X[array_of_indices, *] # edit * to allow variable number of dims
```

I want to be able to feed it various sized tensors and get the indexed slices out as a batch. Such as:

```
A = torch.rand(1000, 3, 32, 32)
B = torch.rand(1000, 5, 20)

indices = np.arange(10)

A_batch = masktensor(A, indices)
B_batch = masktensor(B, indices)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial and error, I found that `...` works as a slice wildcard:

```
def masktensor(X, array_of_indices):
    return X[array_of_indices, ...] # <---- '...' allows variable dim size

A = torch.rand(1000, 3, 32, 32)
B = torch.rand(1000, 5, 20)

indices = np.arange(10)

print(masktensor(A, indices).size())
print(masktensor(B, indices).size())
```

Yields:

```
>>> torch.Size([10, 3, 32, 32])
>>> torch.Size([10, 5, 20])
```